# Prove this result relating to the sign of a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Suppose that $\phi \in S_n$ is a permutation.
Suppose also that $\psi = \phi \circ (i,j),$ where $1 \leq i, j \leq n.$
Why does it follow that sign$(\phi) = $ $-$sign$(\psi)$?

Comment: The $\forall $ makes little sense here

Comment: Do you know that sign is a homomorphism?

Comment: How do you define sign?

Comment: @MattSamuel I believe it's $-1$ if there are an odd number of transpositions and $+1$ otherwise.

Comment: @GregoryGrant that's one definition. There are multiple definitions, I'm trying to find out which one we're using.

Comment: Can you prove that sign is well-defined? i.e. given 2 representations of $\phi$ as a product of transpositions, can you prove they have the same sign?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Of course, you are right.  I was copying this from part of a larger problem and forgot to exclude the $\forall $ symbol.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I have just looked up the definition of homomorphism.  How does the definition help me with my question, please?

Comment: @MattSamuel: The definition I am using is the one given by Gregory Grant.

Comment: My first paragraph deals with that. $\psi$ has one more transposition.

Comment: @MattSamuel: I will look at that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the definition of sign in terms of transpositions, this is a one line proof. Namely, if $\phi$ is a product of an odd number of transpositions, then $\psi$ is the product of an even number of transpositions, and vice versa. Hence they have opposite signs.

Less trivial is with the definition in terms of inversions (odd number of inversions means sign $-1$, even number sign $1$). Suppose $\phi$ has $n$ inversions. Define

$a$= the number of indices $k$ with $i<k<j$ such that $\phi(i)>\phi(k)$

$b$= the number of indices $k$ with $i<k<j$ such that $\phi(i)<\phi(k)$

$c$= the number of indices $k$ with $i<k<j$ such that $\phi(j)>\phi(k)$

$d$= the number of indices $k$ with $i<k<j$ such that $\phi(j)<\phi(k)$

Then the number of inversions of $\psi$ is 
$$n-a+b+c-d+1$$
But $a+b=c+d=j-i-1$, because they are both equal to the number of indices between $i$ and $j$, so $-a+b+c-d$, which has the same parity as $a+b+c+d$, is even, hence the number of inversions of $\psi$ has the opposite parity of the number of inversions of $\phi$ (from the $+1$ summand) hence they have opposite signs.

Comment: In regards to the first paragraph, I am not fully sure why $\psi$ necessarily  has opposite sign to $\phi.$  What is the effect on a permutation (written as a product of transpositions) of interchanging two of its elements, as is done in my original question?

Comment: @CKKOY do you know what a transposition is?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  A transposition is a permutation of $X_n$ that interchanges two elements $i, j$ of $X_n$ and leaves all other elements unchanged.

Comment: @CKKOY correct. An example of a transposition is $(ij)$. Write $\phi$ as a product of transpositions. Put $(ij)$ to the right. Then you have written $\psi$ as a product of transpositions with one more term in the product.

Comment: Of course!  I have just seen that this follows so simply from the definition of $\psi.$  I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: @CKKOY no problem.